# Подскажите, какие закрывающие операции нужно сделать, чтобы не было утечек из SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Пользуюсь SQLite. Появляется следующий лог:

> A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch/databases/database.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Курсоры я закрыл. Но надпись появляется. Подскажите, что нужно ещё закрывать по умолчанию при пользовании SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что закоммитили все транзакции.

А чтобы не гоняться за всеми объектами, засуньте подключение в синглтон. См. [SQLite Connection leaked although everything closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18148718/293099).

Comment: "Закоммитили транзакции"... Можно поподробнее?

Comment: "засуньте подключение в синглтон" - в идеале, используйте пул соединений вроде  C3P0 или boneCP

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов `setTransactionSuccessful`. Начните со второго пункта. :)